# How to control the precision of the scikit-learn decision tree algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, precision, decision-tree

I am using the scikit-learn decision trees for a classification problem.
My input data has a precision of 4 decimal points. However, due to [binary representation errors](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) it is possible that they internal numpy representation may have more than 4 decimal points of significance.

Is there a way for me to instruct the sklearn algorithm **not to use threshold values of more than 4 decimal points** when computing the binary tree? Otherwise I'm afraid that the results could be meaningless at large depths.

Comment: can you try to use: [numpy.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) and see if it works? Also keep in mind that "set_printoptions" only affects arrays since printing of arrays is under the control of numpy. On the other hand, printing of scalars and scalar arrays is handed off to python which
doesn't have a set_printoptions.

Comment: @reMJ have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to avoid the numeric errors associated to floating point representation in the construction of a decision tree would consist in using integers rather than floats to fit the model. If your input data has a precision of 4 digits you just need to multiply it by 10<sup>4</sup> and the round to the nearest integer and cast the result to integer like this:

```python
input_data = np.int32(np.around(input_data * 10**4))
```

Through this feature scaling the condition thresholds are computed more accurately.

#### Demo

```python
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: input_data = np.array([0.0020, 17.0001, 531.4679])

In [4]: np.set_printoptions(precision=32)

In [5]: input_data
Out[5]: 
array([  2.00000000000000004163336342344337e-03,
         1.70000999999999997669419826706871e+01,
         5.31467899999999985993781592696905e+02])

In [6]: input_data = np.int32(np.around(input_data * 10**4))

In [7]: input_data
Out[7]: array([     20,  170001, 5314679])
```